# Как понять, из какой ячейки нажата кнопка?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

В `TableViewCell` есть кнопка. Когда я жму на нее, то вызываю процедуру

```
- (IBAction)PressButton:(id)sender
```

Как в этой процедуре понять, какую ячейку я обрабатываю? Что-то типа: `sender.parent.index`?

Comment: @Indeets, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)pressButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender.superview superview]superview];
    // indexPath of cell if needed
    NSIndexPath *textFieldCellIndexPath = [_purchaseTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    . . .  
}
```

Нужно признать что данный хак грязноват. Если в будущем api для UITableViewCell  поменяется то придется его менять. Тем не менее сейчас это работает на приложении распространяемом в  Аппсторе.

Answer (score 1):

Добавляем строчку:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...............

    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(PressButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

и там же метод:

```
-(void)PressButton:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
```

}

Comment: круто! и ведь работает!

Comment: @Indeets, дык, ёлы-палы)))

Answer (score 0):

**Исползуйте блоки!**

**сабклассим UITableViewCell**:

```
@Interface MyButtonedCell : UITableViewCell 
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^buttonPressedHandler)(Void); // <- в последних скобках могут быть параметры, например нажатая кнопка если она нужна void (^buttonPressedHandler)(UIButton*);
@end
```

@implementation MyButtonedCell

```
// в обработчике нажатия кнопки внутри класса ячейки вызываем блок
    - (IBAction)pressed {
           if (self.buttonPressedHandler) {
              self.buttonPressedHandler();
           }
        }
```

[[@end](/users/12803/end)](/users/12803/end)

**в UIViewController**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   MyButtonedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyButtonedCell"];
/* создаем слабую ссылку на self чтобы использовать внутри блока, таким образом предотвращаем retain loop:*/
   __weak MyViewController *self_ = self;
/*сетим кусок кода в ячейку в виде блока, когда кнопка будет нажата этот код отработает, доступны все объекты внутри этого метода, включая tableView, cell и indexPath: */
   cell.buttonPressedHandler = ^{
        [self_ processButtonPressentOnCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   }
   return cell;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, все очень понятно